# Mesh falls apart

Tags: mesh, armature

I'm trying to make an animation for a model I was provided with. The model is an imported OBJ file. I didn't do much with it, apart from scaling it to the size it's optimal to work with. I made a rigged skeleton that seems to be working just fine, but when I try to join in object mode the mesh to the armature with automatic weight painting the whole mesh falls apart. The connection is made in object mode with Control+P.

My question is how can I fix this problem?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/JzVCcvN.jpg]

I might add that I'm totally new to this whole thing and I'm learning.

Thank you

Comment: Don't join a mesh to an armature, use an Armature Modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Always apply the scale of your mesh: *Object > Apply > Scale* before using an armature with it. After applying, first select your mesh and after that your armature. Hit <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select *With Automatic Weights* (what you apparently did already). This will add an armature modifier to your mesh.

Generally, try to avoid working with scaled meshes, becuase it often causes problems. If you need to scale, do it in edit mode, so the world scale will stay normalized.